# What is the geometry type if I am having mixed geometry?

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I have a mixed geometry data some belong to MULTIPOLYGON and others belong to MULTIPOLYGONZM and I want to insert the data into one.

Comment: Geometry type "GEOMETRY" accepts anything but some software may give you trouble with such data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to "promote" the MULTIPOLYGONs to MULTIPOLYGONZMs. How you do that depends on the method you are using to do the insert.